# How to make left web zone stay on screen while scrolling?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

i have two web zone i need to have one in the left to stay while the other scroll when the browser's scroll bar scrolls. any suggestions or ideas are welcome

Comment: or even a div tag which can hold links and some texts on the left side ?

Answer (score 2):

don't know why you would do this but if you had to I would open up sharepoint designer, navigate to the page. edit the page and open in advanced mode. Look for the following tag `<WebPartPages:WebPartZone` with a title attribute of zone 1, within that add a styles attribute with display as fixed: `styles="Display:fixed;"`

so should look on the lines of:

`<WebPartPages:WebPartZone id="g_sd23423432434sdfsd" runat="server" title="Zone 1" styles="Display:fixed;"`

as you can see above all I did to zone 1 was add in some custom style to set that zone fixed to the screen. you can play around with the style as you please but I would recommend using your browser first (developer tools by pressing F12 on the browser) to play around before doing any changes through SPD.

a little guid on how to do that:

https://zapier.com/blog/inspect-element-tutorial/

use this as a guide to use SPD on SP online to get to the page and edit.

https://www.brightwork.com/blog/creating-your-own-web-part-page-layout-template#.WAOUCItRHIU

using script editor:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $("#ControlIDOfZone").css( "Display", "Fixed" );

</script>
```

Comment: hi ali, on the left webpartzone there are many links and in the right the contents. once you scroll down the page you wont be able to see the links. that is why i had to do this. Can we use this  script editor?

Comment: ahh i see what you mean, just updated answer.

Comment: i have updated the same with below details with no luck <script type="text/javascript">

   $("#ms-rte-layoutszone-inner").css( "Display", "Fixed" );

</script>

Comment: i couldnt find webpart zone as advised the only line which has something related to the webpart is this <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" ID="Bottom" CssClass="ms-hide" Title="loc:Bottom"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
am i missing something ?

Comment: i presume your referring to the left navigation links? if so add the following in script editor on page: <style>
.ms-core-navigation { DISPLAY: fixed}
</style>

Comment: left navigation is hidden and selected a 3 column layout. I am using the left most one as the navigation now.

Comment: is it possible to show code?

Comment: i have managed it with a div tag . .nav-wrapper {
position: fixed;
overflow-y: scroll;
height:800px;
}